# c# interface return type type (not a mistake)

Tags: c#, types, interface, return

I got something like this:

```
Interface IClass
{
    (something) returnClass();
}

Class Breaker: IClass
{
    Public GIS.Breaker returnClass()
    {
        return new GIS.Breaker();
    }
}

Class Conductor: IClass
{
    Public GIS.Conductor returnClass()
    {
        return new GIS.Conductor();
    }
}
```

Both gis.breaker and gis.conductor are build in classes imported with a dll file....

And now i dont know what to do with the interface...i need it to return a type...not a string...not a double....but a type in general

How to do it?

Comment: Um, `object`? Or maybe make your interface generic? How do you expect anyone to use this? (Note that it would help if your sample code used proper .NET naming conventions, and the appropriate casing for declarations, e.g. `public` instead of `Public`.)

Comment: Sry for the code...i am on phone...not on pc...pls explain ur answer....i thougt to make the type dznamic....could it work?

Comment: Um, maybe. You'd need to change the return types in the implementations, of course. But *please* don't ask a question when you're not in a situation where you can do a good job of it. Wait until you're on a PC, where you can provide suitable context etc. Your question is too unclear to answer at the moment, as we don't know how your interface will be used.

Comment: I usualy do...but i am out of time :( and on top...no internet...

Comment: Then that's a terrible time to ask a question. Your lack of time is no excuse for asking a bad question.

Comment: Are you loading the assembly by your self? of do you create a reference to it.

Comment: guys, i already found the answer to it....below this...ty for all

Answer (score 2):

Breaker and Conductor must implement some common interface or you can make IClass generic.

```
interface IClass<T>
{
    T ReturnClass();
}

class Breaker: IClass<GIS.Breaker>
{
    public GIS.Breaker ReturnClass()
    {
        return new GIS.Breaker();
    }
}

class Conductor: IClass<GIS.Conductor>
{
    public GIS.Conductor ReturnClass()
    {
        return new GIS.Conductor();
    }
}
```

But I think it's bad idea to combine instance builders and objects.